# Frequency that quartz crystal can handle

Tags: oscillator, crystal, resonance

I understand that when an applied voltage signal enters the quartz crystal, it mechanically vibrates. Now, let's say that the voltage is 1 kHz and the quartz crystal is 32.728 kHz, can the quartz crystal handle that? Does it also follow that the frequency of the applied should not surpass that of the quartz crystal? Thanks.

Comment: Think of pushing a pendulum or swing at the wrong frequency. Much of your work will be spent stopping and reversing the momentum. Hit it at the right frequency and phase and each push causes the amplitude to increase.

Comment: If you apply a signal with a frequency that is lower or higher than the resonant frequency of the crystal, the crystal will have a **high impedance** meaning, it will not absorb any current and it will appear as if the crystal is "not there". Only when you apply a frequency that is very close to resonant frequency, will the crystal respond, similar to a pendulum as in Transistor's comment. So oscillator circuits "interact" with the crystal in such a way that there's an exchange of electrical energy at the resonance frequency.

Comment: Thank you, @Bimpelrekkie and Transistor. I now understand its utility better.

Answer (score 4):

Except at its resonant frequency, a quartz crystal will not significantly mechanically respond to an input frequency. Therefore it will not be damaged. Only at or very near its resonant frequency will the crystal vibration amplitude be significant.  If the input voltage is then too high, the crystal vibration amplitude could exceed its mechanical strength capability and it could then be damaged. The very high mechanical Q of the crystal prevents this from happening at frequencies off resonance.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This can all be pretty much simulated. Take this equivalent circuit of a 10.000000 MHz crystal: -

[image]

Then if you plot the crystal's impedance you'll get a response that pretty much looks like a fairly high impedance everywhere except around where it resonates: -

[image]

The impedance response above is from 9.99 MHz to 10.01 MHz.

So, if you apply a voltage at the series resonant frequency (10.000000 MHz) you could destroy the device because it (the example) only has 20 Ω impedance and it usually only takes (give or take) a few tens to a few hundreds of micro-watts to cause many crystals to fail. There will be exceptions of course but 32.768 kHz are usually very low power devices because they are used in battery powered equipment.

If you apply a voltage at the parallel resonant frequency, the impedance is so high that barely any current flows and barely any power is dissipated.

> *Now, let's say that the voltage is 1 kHz and the quartz crystal is
> 32.728 kHz, can the quartz crystal handle that?*

I really don't see that being a problem but the devil is in the details of how much voltage you apply. If you want a more definitive answer, numbers are required. For instance, in the device simulated above, at 10.000000 MHz the impedance is 20 Ω yet at 9.998 MHz the impedance has risen sharply to 1 kΩ.

> *Does it also follow that the frequency of the applied should not
> surpass that of the quartz crystal?*

No, that doesn't follow.